# Calling the Eigen method .row() causes unexpected main program crash after related thread termination

Tags: c++, multithreading, eigen

I have a large **C++ multi-thread Visual Studio framework**. The main process launches a set of threads to run different routines simultaneously, and then waits for joining them. However, at run time, I experienced an unexpected behavior, as the **main program terminates and closes before joining all the threads**, but no asserts, exceptions or error messages are shown from the command line.

After several trials and debugging actions, I could isolate a single atomic change between a properly working behavior of the program (correct thread joining and termination) and the undesired one. In particular, **I observed that the main program unexpectedly terminates after the end of a thread callback calling the Eigen method `.row()` on an Eigen matrix**: the thread callback seems to correctly execute the related instruction (i.e., the output vector is successfully assigned to the selected row of the input matrix) and finish properly but, for some reason, the main thread is not able to join it and terminates immediately. **If I substitute the call to the `.row()` method with an explicit element-wise assignment of the vector**, this behavior does not occur, **the main thread properly joins** and the program continues and terminates as expected.

I don't really know if the issue that I'm experiencing is somehow caused by this Eigen method, but I couldn't find any other discriminating factor to debug the problem.

Does anybody have a possible idea or suggestion about the reason underlying this problem? I am aware that the formulation of my question is really general and could be due to a huge set of causes, but I am not even able to guess where I need to put the focus on to solve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a [repro] for the issue.

Comment: *I*'m *guessing* a data race somewhere due to lack of synchronization and subsequent [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: I apologize with both of you, I am well aware that a minimal reproducible example would ease the comprehension of the problem, but my frustration in the last two days was so intense that I couldn't figure out how to wrap a minimal portion of code. Indeed, I'm guessing as well it could be due to data race; if so, posting here is probably not the best method to approach the issue. Thanks you anyway for your interest, I appreciate it.